# Wildcard path proxy to Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I have two cloud run services (Next.js and API server) and I want to serve them through a single endpoint.
I want requests to `/api` to be forwarded to API service and all other other requests (`/*`) to be forwarded to Next.js server.
[Cloud Run documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run) suggests that I use Endpoint but it does not seem to support wildcard paths.
What are the possible alternatives?

Comment: What about a GCP HTTP Load Balancer that uses Path matching ... see ... https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map#path-matchers

Comment: @Kolban - Google HTTP Load Balancers do not support Cloud Run as a backend.

Comment: For your use case, I would use Firebase to integrate Cloud Run. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container

Comment: @JohnHanley Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I wrote a simple program that serves as api gateway and deployed it as a cloud run service but firebase hosting was enough.

Comment: @hitochan - Firebase is a very cool product/service.

Comment: Now load balancer supports cloud run and functions through serverless Network Endpoint Groups(NEG)

Answer (score 1):

Google API Gateway supports different wildcards, I'using Google Functions as backend, but that shouldn't make a different when using the GW with Google Run.

My scenario:

- `/` should route to the `/index.html`
- `/assets` should route to the `/assets/any-file-here.png`
- `/logo-256.png` should route to the `/logo-256.png`
- `/endpoint-1` should route only to the API, but hosted on another function
- `/endpoint-2/some-param` should route only to the API, hosted on the same function as the assets

With this configuration everything get's routed liked wanted, using [Double Wildcard Matching](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/path-templating#double_wildcard_matching).

It doesn't matter that the wildcard is before specific routes, this is handled correctly by the gateway.

```json
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "title": "Some API w/ Assets"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "home",
                "operationId": "home",
                "parameters": [],
                "x-google-backend": {
                    "address": "https://THE-GOOGLE-RUN-OR-FUNCTION",
                    "path_translation": "CONSTANT_ADDRESS"
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Home"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/{files=**}": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "assets",
                "operationId": "assets",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "path",
                        "name": "files",
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    }
                ],
                "x-google-backend": {
                    "address": "https://THE-GOOGLE-RUN-OR-FUNCTION",
                    "path_translation": "APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS"
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "assets"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/endpoint-1": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Some pure backend api",
                "operationId": "ep1",
                "x-google-backend": {
                    "address": "https://SOME-OTHER-GOOGLE-RUN-OR-FUNCTION",
                    "path_translation": "APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS"
                },
                "parameters": [],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "result values"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/endpoint-2/{some_param}": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Some pure backend API with path param",
                "operationId": "ep2",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "in": "path",
                        "name": "some_param",
                        "type": "string",
                        "required": true
                    }
                ],
                "x-google-backend": {
                    "address": "https://THE-GOOGLE-RUN-OR-FUNCTION",
                    "path_translation": "APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS"
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "result values"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But with this setup, your page won't be that fast, I recommend adding Google Load Balancer with Google CDN before your API gateway when you are serving files.

Answer (score 0):

This is best addressed through the usage of Firebase hosting since they have a [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run#direct_requests_to_container) to do just this.

Hope you find this useful